Extract sub-string within larger block
Given the following partial file:
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - $basearch
# It is much more secure to use the metalink, but if you wish to use a local mirror
# place its address here.
#baseurl=https://download.example/pub/epel/8/Everything/$basearch
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-8&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
disable_repo=zabbix
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
countme=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - $basearch - Debug
# It is much more secure to use the metalink, but if you wish to use a local mirror
# place its address here.
#baseurl=https://download.example/pub/epel/8/Everything/$basearch/debug
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-8&arch=$basearch&infra=$infra&content=$contentdir
enabled=0
disable_repo=test
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-8
gpgcheck=1

I am trying to extract the disable_repo line found within the [epel] block of code so I extract a value of "zabbix".  I can find the right block of text using \[epel\]((?s)(?:(?!\n\n).)*) but am having problems getting it closer than that.

What language are you going to use to extract this? Do you need it just from the [epel] block? Can you grab all matches and discard others?

Why not use a toml library

You can use a negative lookahead assertion to ensure that every character between [epel] and a matching disable_repo=... is not the beginning of another [...] block header, and capture what comes after disable_repo= in a group:
\[epel\]$(?:(?!\[[^]]*\]).)*^disable_repo=([^\n]*)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/QmQdYg/3
Note that the single line mode has to be enabled for . to match any character, including a newline, and the multi-line mode has to be enabled for ^ and $ to match the start and the end of a line rather than the string.

If the format of the file has that structure, you can prevent crossing blocks or matching disable_repo= from the start of the string.
Then match disable_repo= and capture the value in group 1.
^\[epel\](?:\n(?!disable_repo=|\[[^\]\[\n]*\]$).*)*\ndisable_repo=(.*)

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
\[epel\] Match [epel]
(?: Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

\n Match a newline
(?! Negative lookahead

disable_repo= Match literally
| Or
\[[^\]\[\n]*\]$ Match [...] till the end of the string


) Close the lookahead
.* Match the whole line


)*
\ndisable_repo=(.*) Match a newline, disable_repo= and capture the value in group 1

See a regex demo

If your values have no empty lines in between, you can prevent some backtracking when there is no match by not allowing empty lines adding [^\S\n]*$ as a third alternative.
^\[epel\](?:\n(?!disable_repo=|\[[^\]\[\n]*\]$|[^\S\n]*$).*)*\ndisable_repo=(.*)

